# Essas perguntas são duplicadas?

Tags: debate

Casualmente eu vi as duas perguntas que irei listar abaixo e fiquei pensando, **será que são duplicatas**?

As perguntas são:

- [Usar tipo de variável não primitiva em C# pode afetar no desempenho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3255/20615)
- [Qual é a diferença de string vs String?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/20615)

Eu sei que as perguntas possuem muitos votos e são antigas. Porém, se não são consideradas duplicadas eu poderia fazer todo tipo de pergunta sobre cada `alias` que deveria continuar aberta, ou não?

Um exemplo muito claro, é que as duas perguntas possuem as mesmas respostas, que listam os `alias` do `C#`.

Minha dúvida real é:

**Se eu abrir uma pergunta perguntando a diferença entre `int` e System.`Int32`? Poderia fechar como duplicada? E se sim, qual das duas seria a escolhida para marcar?**

Devo ressaltar que essa pergunta não tem o intuíto de desmerecer nenhuma das perguntas/respostas contidas nas duas questões, e como o SOpt diz, ["Adoramos (algumas) duplicadas."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não, embora passa raspando mesmo. Se fechassem eu nem me preocuparia muito (poderia eliminar possíveis concorrentes futuros pra minha :D) . Vejo diferenças suficientes e acho que o cerne de uma é a performance, não perguntada na outra.

Curiosamente as duas respostas que são idênticas não respondem muito bem nenhuma das duas perguntas onde elas estão :) Não que tenha algo errado ou esteja incompleta, mas a informação principal não era tão importante como parte central (nenhuma crítica a elas também)

Este é um dos casos que talvez as respostas de uma das perguntas não se prenderam tanto ao que foi perguntado (ainda que tenha sido respondido porque não afeta o desempenho).

Note ainda que a mais antiga tem uma afirmação incorreta sobre tipos primitivos que não existe em C#. Quase dei uma resposta lá por causa disto, o comentário ficou muito resumido. A resposta aceita seria uma que eu daria quase palavra por palavra :) Obviamente eu só seria mais completo :P Aaah, vá?!?! Logo eu? :D

É claro que se ficarem perguntado para cada alias acho que vira sacanagem. Claro que tem que ver a pergunta concreta para saber como votar, pode ter uma pequeno detalhes que faça ela ser suficientemente diferente, mas se não tiver, tem que fechar. É o tipo da coisa que não consigo dar uma resposta clara para todos os casos. Se for só isto colocado na edição da pergunta, aí dá pra afirmar que deve fechar. Não tem mais nada pra acrescentar.

Se for duplicata mesmo, em geral a mais nova é fechada, mas isso não é regra absoluta. Tem até situação que o sistema nem deixa fechar. Mesmo outros casos cabe o bom senso de cada um. Imagine deixar um pergunta ruim aberta talvez com resposta errada em detrimento de outra duplicata mais nova boa e com resposta correta. Eu acho melhor deixar a melhor aberta, mas isso não é algo fixo. tem que ver o caso concreto. Note que este tipo de dilema será bem raro.

Comment: Entendo e concordo com o que disse. Mas minha dúvida é: Se eu abrir uma pergunta perguntando a diferença entre `int` e `System.Int32`? Poderia fechar como duplicada? E se sim, qual das duas seria a escolhida para marcar?

Comment: Concordo plenamente com isso **" Eu acho melhor deixar a melhor aberta"**. Mas porque não começar com essas de uma vez, ao esperar aparecer outro caso (se é que irá aparecer). Note que eu me refiro somente a marcar uma como duplicada e não excluir. :p

Comment: Aí está no começo da resposta. Se quiser puxar, puxe, eu acho que não é dup.

Comment: Vamos ver no que vai dar. Mas acho que não dará em nada.